# Oracle 11 está expirando as senhas. Como faço para redefinir isso?

Tags: oracle

Migrei recentemente (seis meses atras) para o Oracle 11 e agora ao usar o comando 
`sqlplus system@INTANCIA` passei a receber a mensagem abaixo:

```
ORA-28002: the password will expire within 7 days
```

OBS: Ainda estou conseguindo me logar e ele apenas avisa que a senha será expirada em breve.

Como faço para configurar meu SGBD para não solicitar troca de senha. Trata-se de ambiente de **Desenvolvimento** e não tenho requisitos de segurança neste nível. Prefiro não introduzir mais complexidade nos Scripts por menores que sejam.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para verificar qual o nome do profile associado a um dado conjunto de usuários faça:

```
SELECT username, profile FROM dba_users 
WHERE username in ('SYSTEM', 'HR');
```

Para verificar como está definida uma certa Profile (em relação a definição de PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME) faça:

```
select resource_type, limit 
from dba_profiles 
where profile='DEFAULT' 
  and resource_name = 'PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME';
```

Para alterar de forma que o Oracle não expire mais as senhas use:

```
ALTER PROFILE DEFAULT LIMIT PASSWORD_LIFE_TIME UNLIMITED;
```